# Python retrieve values in list from set of tuples

Tags: python

Suppose I have a ordered list here called T

```
T = ['foo', 'bar', 'cad']
```

I then have a set M containing tuples.

```
M = { 
        ('jack', 'bar'), 
        ('bob', 'foo'), 
        ('let', 'cad') 
    }
```

For every item in T, I want to find the corresponding tuple pair in M.
So my output would look like the following list

```
O = [ 'bob', 'jack', 'let' ]
```

I tried this set comprehension but this of course just iterated the elements as defined in the order of M, **I need to define it in the order of T.**

```
answer = [ a for (a,b) in R if b in T ]
```

As a follow up question, say my M looked like:

```
M = { 
        ('bar', 'jack'), 
        ('foo', 'bob'), 
        ('cad', 'let') 
    }
```

Does this make this easier to solve?

Is it possible to solve this without using a dict? Purely lists, sets and tuples?

Comment: Your expected output is not possible, in the sense that you expect a set in a specific order, but sets are unordered.

Comment: If you need some order, build a list instead of a set

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part I want my expected answer to be a List.

Comment: @DanielJ if an answer here solves your problem, please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T = ['foo', 'bar', 'cad']

M = { 
        ('jack', 'bar'), 
        ('bob', 'foo'), 
        ('let', 'cad') 
    }

d = {k:v for (v,k) in M}

answer = [d[elt] for elt in T]

print(answer)
# ['bob', 'jack', 'let']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
T = ['foo', 'bar', 'cad']
M = { 
        ('jack', 'bar'), 
        ('bob', 'foo'), 
        ('let', 'cad') 
    }

# Solution 1 - Order is different everytime
a = [x for (x, y) in M if y in T]
print(a)

# Solution 2 - Give you answer in same order always
MT = {y:x for (x, y) in M}
a = [MT[i] for i in T]
print(a)
```

You can try this.